# lsmod returns error unless called with sudo

Tags: kernel-modules

Fixed: The install README for libusb suggests added a call to

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libusb-driver.so
```

It was this .so file that was getting called and interefering with lsmod (and it turns out some other commands as well). To fix this I moved the libusb-driver.so file to the Xilinx/.../common/bin/lin64 folder. All tools can access the cable without sudo calls.

In addition I found that the Xilinx settingsXX.sh script was breaking my PATH. Changed this script to append to end of PATH instead of front of PATH.

Thanks Y'all.

Fedora 17, Linux 3.4.4

After installing the Xilinx cable drivers, which didn't work with Linux 3.4.4 I installed the libusb solution. The cables detect and I can access them from within the Xilinx tools. However, now everytime I try an lsmod I get the following error:

```
libkmod: kmod_module_get_holders: could not open '/sys/module/windrvr6/holders': No such file or directory
windrvr6                   1  -2 

libkmod: kmod_module_get_holders: could not open '/sys/module/parport_pc/holders': No such file or directory
parport_pc
```

sudo lsmod does work, and these modules are not shown as loaded. rmmod reports that the modules aren't loaded. 
I have poked around /sys/module , /etc/modprobe.d and a couple of locations I can't recall at this second. I can find no reference to windrvr6 anywhere.

Any suggestions about how to remove calls to these modules would be great. 
I also tried making a new user and the problem persists there. I logged in as root and the problem persists there as well, unless I call lsmod with sudo, it errors.

Thanks,
Camille

Comment: Is there a special `lsmod` in `/etc/sudoers`?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: The install README for libusb suggests added a call to

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libusb-driver.so
```

It was this .so file that was getting called and interefering with lsmod (and it turns out some other commands as well). To fix this I moved the libusb-driver.so file to the Xilinx/.../common/bin/lin64 folder. All tools can access the cable without sudo calls.

In addition I found that the Xilinx settingsXX.sh script was breaking my PATH. Changed this script to append to end of PATH instead of front of PATH.

Thanks Y'all.